# Is my top statement saying my asterisk server is using too much resources?

Tags: linux, top, asterisk

I installed an asterisk server on my VPS with linode.  I have 1 GB of ram. I'm not sure what kind of CPU is in use.

I decided to test the number of concurrent calls my system can handle.  So I used a script call "sipp" to help me with this. When creating the test calls, it seems my asterisk server can only take up to about 250 or so calls, then drops the remaining.  I see messages like `WARNING[8314]: rtp.c:2433 rtp_socket: Unable to allocate RTP socket: Too many open files` in my asterisk terminal.

So I decided to run `top` to see how hard my server is working.  Below is a screenshot of what I see:

[image]

I've tried reading tutorials on how to understand this, but I still don't fully understand.  My understanding is that the 97.0%id means I have 97% of the CPU available?  And the first line in the table shows asterisk using 64% of the cpu.  But the 64% and 97% adds up to more than 100%, which isn't what I was expecting.  Why is this so?

And my final question is, just by looking at this table, can one say if it's the CPU or memory that is limiting my number of concurrent calls to about 250 calls?

Comment: In that photo, `asterisk` is using 64% of the CPU, so according to what I can see in that photo (assuming it's sorted by CPU), there is 36% of free cpu.

Comment: How many virtual CPUs do you have?

Comment: I think i might have 2 virtual CPUs?  i'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the CPU and memory usage aren't limiting you; the permissible number of open files for the asterisk user is. This can be adjusted by setting ulimit/sysctl settings. The HOW will depend on your Linux distribution.

Comment: ulimit says unlimited.  I updated my fs.file-max from 102772 to 99999999, but still no effect.  The calls still drop somewhere between 245 and 255.

Comment: Ok, your answer got me most of the way there.  I ended up editing the `/etc/init.d/asterisk` file and I added `ulimit -n 2048` at the top of hte script.